# My Samsung Galaxy S6 is bricked

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I recently bricked my Samsung Galaxy S6 SM-S906l while trying to flash TWRP recovery.

Apparently, it was an unsupported recovery and I need to reflash the original recover with Odin, but it says it needs the PIT file.

How do you obtain the PIT file?

Comment: Tightly related [post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150385/request-for-pit-file-galaxy-s6), if not duplicate. The problem is the same, making this a dual-prong appeal to action.

Comment: but i need help! My phone is bricked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SM-S906L` is the same device as the `SM-G920V` [[source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-s6/help/update-sm-g920v-vzw-sm-s906l-st-t3374291)]. You should be able to use the PIT for the `SM-G920V`. You can get the PIT [here](http://us.samfirm.net/threads/g920v-rom-full-android-6-0-1-galaxy-s6-sm-g920v-g920vvru4cpc2-vzw.81/).

I also found it [here](http://ir-file.com/?p=Firmware/samsung/original/s-series/sm-s906l/sm-s906l_pit) (and it is labeled as the `SM-S906L`, but has the same file name as the one that is specified for the `SM-G920V`).